# Is Stack Overflow down, or is it just me?

Tags: support

I have not been able to access Stack Overflow for the past 1 hour. All attempts to access the web site returned one of these errors:

- I/O error
- Connection failure
- Fastly error: unknown domain

Comment: Ah glad to know it isn't just me

Comment: Using Meta to ask about issues with Stack Overflow is somewhat like when your ISP tells you to send them an email when your Internet is down. :-)

Comment: some parts seem more affected than others. For instance https://stackoverflow.com/jobs seems especially affected

Comment: There are sites which check if a site is down/up (or users can report it themselves), there you can usually quickly see if a site broke and it is in fact not a you-problem. I just googled "stackoverflow down" and the first hit made it abundantly clear.

Comment: actually I knew the problem, but just wondered how other users and staffs feel about it but dunno how to ask it.

Comment: How other users and staff feel about it? As soon as Stack Overflow goes down the global water level rises due to all the nervous sweating.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, I could reproduce this problem only a few moments ago. Fastly CDN was temporarily down, which took down a large chunk of the Internet. (Remember when the Internet was supposed to be a distributed network, where if one portion went offline, it had no effect on other portions?)

Everything seems back to normal, but this may be geographically dependent. Either way, it's not a Stack Overflow issue; give it some time, and it should resolve itself.

Comment: Partly fixed because the SRE team are re-routing traffic: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1402215240276774915

Comment: Picturing Nick Craver sitting there in his pajamas, manually rerouting traffic and giving out "#hugops".

Comment: i doubt that they fixed the problem jet

Comment: Why was Fastly CDN down?

Comment: Ask Fastly, @КонстантинВан. Maybe one can post a question on meta.fastly.com...