# Fastly error: unknown domain

Tags: bug

Since yesterday I've encountered following error a couple of times:

> Fastly error: unknown domain: stackoverflow.com. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.
>
> Details: cache-fra-eddf8230041-FRA

I have seen Fastly [being mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408233) a couple times in past here. I assume this is on Stack Overflow's side.

Usually the cited error is shown for 5-10 minutes, and then everything is back.

But the laptop on which I've seen this error is my employer's device, so I'm not 100% sure in what's happening with its networking. I haven't seen this error on a phone yet, but I'm using it way less.

Is this error on my side or somewhere within the delivery chain?

Comment: Is this shown in the browser instead of the page? Or is it something you saw in the network request, for example?

Comment: Does your employer have their own DNS for their devices? Stack Overflow recently [changed their IP addresses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393039/stack-exchange-network-sites-ip-addresses-may-change-in-the-coming-weeks) so that might be the cause. One way to check would be to see what an nslookup returns to you for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @VLAZ, it's shown in browser instead of the page

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, yes it does. I'll try to check this.

Comment: Yep, nslookup returned addresses like 151.101.65.69, but Google dns says it's actually two addresses like 104.18.22.201

Comment: @markalex nslookup reports 104.18.22.201 and 104.18.23.201 for me.

Comment: Also on MSE: [Error: Unknown domain: stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393415)

Comment: Also getting the error, from Spain.Tried to update Windows DNS to CloudFlare's 1.1.1.1 but still getting the error

Answer (score 11):

I can reproduce your error by editing my [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file and adding an entry for Stack Overflow (won't recommend doing this with random IP addresses in an uncontrolled manner!) pointing to the IP address provided in your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426682/fastly-error-unknown-domain#comment974285_426682), so this is due to the IP address change and is due to the DNS used by your employer. You should inform your employer about this change and ask them to get it fixed.

Comment: I would assume a proper DNS server honors the TTL for the DNS records they have cached. That should resolve the issue *eventually ...*

Comment: Same thing happening to me for SO and for .stackexchange, from Madrid (works fine with 5g, but not wifi. I tried changing DNS but it didn't help, so I'm guessing some CDN outage in Europe or something...)

Comment: @JuanTonina that's likely not a CDN outage, Stack Overflow used to use Fastly but have switched to Cloudflare. If you're still hitting Fastly the DNS is most likely the issue.

Comment: I'm facing the same problems too. My ISP is Finetwork and I'm in Madrid. On 5G it loads, but on WiFi I get the error. @AbdulAzizBarkat how to solve this? I've tried changing Window's DNS but still get the error.

Comment: @Marcos, my DNS switches back and forth between correct and incorrect addresses for some reason. As a temporary workaround, until things settle down, I've added `104.18.22.201 stackoverflow.com` to hosts file (and same for meta).

Comment: I am experiencing the same, based in Switzerland, for about two weeks now. If I use WARP Cloudflare, circumventing my ISP, it works. I am using 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 as the DNS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's only an issue on my end but if anyone used `104.18.22.201 stackoverflow.com` but got a page with no styling (CSS) try adding this `104.18.22.201 cdn.sstatic.net` **at the next line**, it works for me ;)