# Why is CSS content not loading in my browser?

Tags: support, design

I'm experiencing an issue where the CSS on Stack Overflow is not loading properly. When I visit the website, it appears that the styles are not being applied, resulting in an unstyled page.

I'm using Google Chrome, but I've also tried Firefox.

Here are the specific details of the problem:

[image]

Comment: If it's occuring on both this sounds more like it's being blocked by your device/networks firewall, service provider, or perhaps the great fire wall.

Comment: It appears that most or all of the Stack Exchange specific resources are being blocked (e.g., everything from cdn.sstatic.net, both JS and CSS). This is most likely to be done by your browser, a browser extension (which could be installed in both browsers), your operating system (e.g., firewall settings), or somewhere in the network connection you are using (e.g., work, ISP, country, etc.). It is likely not an issue specific to Stack Exchange, other than the block is on a domain that Stack Exchange uses. You will need to do investigation on your end to find where the block is and resolve it.

Comment: It *might* be more wide-spread than that (2023-10-10T181532Z+0). E.g., try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77268114/edit) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268114/how-to-fix-ubuntu-partition-not-resizing). Back to the mechanical keyboard rabbit hole!

Comment: A 5xx error indicates a server-side issue. There's currently [an editing issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393681/i-cant-edit-anything-on-mse-right-now-http-500-an-error-occurred-submitting) network-wide that's also returning 500s. And just a moment ago I wasn't able to load any posts on Meta SO.

Comment: OK, it seems to have been (mostly) resolved by now (2023-10-10T183527Z+0).

Comment: If you are still facing this issue, I believe it is due to the IP address change Stack Overflow did recently. See: [Fastly error: unknown domain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426682/fastly-error-unknown-domain) (The reason I believe this to be the issue is due to some debugging info provided in: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426837/getting-internal-server-errors-http-500-on-js-css-assets-when-loading-the-main)