# Getting internal server errors (HTTP 500) on JS/CSS assets when loading the main site

Tags: bug

I got these errors in the dev tools: [image: picture of error messages in devtools]

This is the network tab:
[image]

The request, in greater detail:
[image]

There's no CSS, nothing works, some buttons just redirect you back to the home page. It doesn't work in Brave, Chrome, Edge or Firefox.

Comment: Seems that [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426813/why-is-css-content-not-loading-in-my-browser) hasn't been fully resolved.

Comment: Can you share more details from the network tab in the devtools? Is there any data returned along with the 500 status code.

Comment: Clearly, the platform doesn’t exist.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why is CSS content not loading in my browser?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426813/why-is-css-content-not-loading-in-my-browser). However, please add more details to the question as much as possible to help the developers in troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: It appears that most or all of the Stack Exchange specific resources are being blocked (e.g., everything from cdn.sstatic.net, both JS and CSS). This is most likely to be done by your browser, a browser extension (which could be installed in both browsers), your operating system (e.g., firewall settings), or somewhere in the network connection you are using (e.g., work, ISP, country, etc.). It is likely not an issue specific to Stack Exchange, other than the block is on a domain that Stack Exchange uses. You will need to do investigation on your end to find where the block is and resolve it.

Comment: Given that you are seeing the issue in multiple disparate browsers, it's more likely to be an issue at your operating system level or a block somewhere in your network connection. Without significantly more information, which will likely require more investigation on your part regarding your OS and network, there's likely not all that much which we or the company can do. It's *possible* that there's a misconfiguration somewhere by Stack Exchange, but if that was the case, we'd expect there to be multiple other people seeing similar issues.

Comment: At the very least, the whole HTTP response would be a useful thing to have, to see where it seems to be generated. It's sad you didn't provide it directly, considering you were already only one click away from the network inspector.

Comment: @yivi A bit passive aggressive. I didn't consider it because I just saw errors that seemed like that didn't have anything to do with the network. I'll check later

Comment: I apologize. I didn’t mean it that way, but I see now it was poorly phrased.

Comment: @yivi it's ok. Is there anything else that could be useful for detecting the error? It's certainly not a browser related issue, because I tried it on 4 different ones, and Firefox isn't Chromium based either. Also there are no browser extensions, except for Brave.

Comment: The full HTTP response would be the most useful to show it’s not browser related, IMO. You can get/copy that from the network tab of the dev tools.

Comment: @yivi edited the question

Comment: I see the response's content type is "text/html" that means there should be some content in the response, you're currently showing us the headers tab for that request, the response tab would be useful as well.

Comment: In any case, the 500 response comes from the right domain, from an IP address that belongs to fastly and with varnish heaeders, so it all looks like a server side issue, and not a client or firewall issue. True, given that SO is laying off people atm, maybe it's not a great time for get support for something like this. :(

Comment: @yivi wait the IP address belongs to Fastly? Yeah, that's the problem then. Stack Overflow has shifted over to Cloudflare, if the request is still going to Fastly the DNS is the problem. See: [Fastly error: unknown domain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426682/fastly-error-unknown-domain). Given its been around a month since that I would have thought the DNS records would have been updated by now...